# Can i use Info Path to create a for an use it on a "non-sharepoint" environtment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, webforms, infopath

I've been researching on this and read some of previous Q&As but they are somehow very abstracts. Suppose I have an ASP.NET site (Web Form with Master Page) and I want to integrate this Excel form which it is easier for me to emulate in Info Path in my ASP.NET site(non-sharepoint environment). Is it possible for me to create this form in Info Path and added it to my ASP.NET Web Form?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried?  If so, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to see that how InfoPath form works. its not the same way as Web Forms. InfoPath forms are xml based forms, these xml based forms are easy to integrate in SharePoint as the data in xml format along with the template is stored in database, but Web form's functionality is different. As for as your question can you please elaborate more how you want to integrate excel form with WebForm.
thanks

Comment: I guessed it would be easier, rather than create a web form emulating the functionality of any spreadsheet in excel, doing it using InfoPath and then apply that to a web form. Given your answer and in general terms, is there a way to implement that XML format into a asp web form?

Answer (score 0):

You can create InfoPath forms to submit to a web service or a Database (start by opening InfoPath Designer and you'll see a bunch of options for advanced templates), plus InfoPath forms store data in good old XML, so you can use pretty much any scripting/server-side technology to parse them if you know where they're stored...

In short the answer is definitely yes, you can use InfoPath forms in non-SharePoint environments, you just have to do the legwork to setup where they submit and then how you fetch that data yourself.